# Desktop Notification Using SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, signalr, desktop

I am trying to achieve Desktop Notifications using SignalR. I am new to signalR.
For example if I change anything into the database it should be displayed onto our computer even if the webapp is closed in the browser but the user is logged in. Nowadays we have the facebook notifications which are displayed onto the screen.

Comment: What have you tried so far??

Comment: Does https://forums.asp.net/t/2106946.aspx?How+to+display+desktop+notifications+Push+notifications+from+asp+net+website+even+after+it+closed+by+user+ help?